# Jenkins - IBM UrbanCode - AWS & Azure cloud

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-cloudformation, ibm-cloud

For [continuous delivery](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/493), we do manual deployment after generating binary artifacts from Jenkins pipeline(in an automated process).

Further, 
for [continuous deployment](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/493), we would like to use IBM UrbanCode tool to automate provisioning and configuration of services  on  both AWS cloud and Azure cloud.

---

1) Does IBM UrbanCode tool help provisioning and configuration of services to AWS and Azure cloud?

2) Does Jenkins support plugin to work with IBM UrbanCode deploy tool? To deploy on AWS and Azure cloud

Comment: IBM UrbanCode has a plugin that launches EC2 instance from an AMI and I add them to the Security Group and Load Balancer groups: https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/amazonec2-udeploy/